# Can a friend function change private data in the class?

Tags: c++

I would like to know if a friend function can change private data in the class without using a

pointer and sending out the object.

I mean does a friend function have access like a member function?

For Example:

```
    class myinfo {
       private:
          char name[20];
          int id;
          float income;         
       public:
          void showInfo(void);
          myinfo(void);
          friend void updateInfo(myinfo);

      int main ( ) {

      myinfo j;
       updateInfo(j); // calling the friend function

   return 0;
}

    void updateInfo(myinfo c) {
       strcat(c.name, ":updated");
       c.id++;
       c.income += 1.1;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but not the way you've written it... If you want the function to modify the passed in object, accept a *reference* rather than by value...

It appears you've not learned about [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29) in c++.

```
// Declaration of function in class
friend void updateInfo(myinfo&);
```

implementation

```
void updateInfo(myinfo& c)
{
  strcat(c.name, ":updated");  // now modifying passed in instance of c.
  c.id++;
  c.income += 1.1;
}
```

Btw. on a side note, prefer to use `std::string` and also learn about *rule of three* (specially for non-trivial classes such as this).

Comment: Sorry I have changed my code a bit it was a mistake I use an example from my work but that doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: can you give a bit explanation or example of reference? Thanks

Comment: @Ali, I don't get your comment, I see you changed the code, but as it stands, the function still accepts `myinfo` by value, so `c` is a copy (default copy), and you modify this temporary. You need to change the signature to accept a reference if you want to modify the passed in instance...

Comment: the meaning of reference are you referring to a pointer? I'm kinda confuse sorry about that.

Comment: This is a reference: `void updateInfo(myinfo &c);` you can use c normally. A pointer would also do, but you would need to use it like a pointer (with `*` and `->` operators).

Comment: @Nim, Thank you so much this helped me to understand more and I will be so prepare for my next quiz :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In principle, private and protected members of a class cannot be accessed from outside the same class in which they are declared. However, this rule does not affect friends.

Friends are functions or classes declared with the friend keyword.

If we want to declare an external function as friend of a class, thus allowing this function to have access to the private and protected members of this class, we do it by declaring a prototype of this external function within the class, and preceding it with the keyword friend.

See it here - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/